# Echo form and reload on same page after submit

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a form that is being displayed by echo, i am trying to refresh the page after submit so that the login attempt can be added to count currently when invalid details are entered the form is displayed but page not refreshed again to add to count, this is what i have:

```
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

  $max_time_in_seconds = 10;

  $max_attempts = 3;




if(login_attempt_count($max_time_in_seconds, $pdo) <= $max_attempts) {

    $form = "<form name='login' class='profile' id='form_id' action=''   
    method='post' accept-charset='utf-8'>
    <fieldset>
            <legend>Login</legend>
            <label for='username'>User name</label>
            <input type='text' name='username' id='username' autofocus  
            placeholder='User name MAX 10'  maxlength='10' title='You can 
            use characters & numbers' required />
            <label for='password'>Password</label>
            <input type='password' id='password' name='password'  
             />
             <br>
            <input type='submit' class='btn' value='Login' id='submit'   
             onSubmit='window.parent.location.reload();' />

           </form>";  
} else {

   $msg2 = " You have been BLOCKED try again in 10 minutes";



}
```

If i refresh the page three times i get blocked, this is what i want if submit is entered three times
I have tried adding

```
       <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>
```

i just get blank white screen...

```
         if($_SESSION['user'] { header("location: memberlist.php");  }
         else
         if($_SESSION['user']['blacklisted_users'] == 'blocked') {       
         header("location: blocked.php");}
         else



        header("Location: private.php");
        die("Redirecting to: private.php");
         }

        else
         {

        $msg = " Username or Password INCORRECT";

          }
```

I think the final else is stopping the page from refreshing because it is just echoing error

Login check:

```
      $query = "
        SELECT
            id,
            username,
            password,
            salt,
            email,
            firstname,
            surname,
            address,
            town,
            postcode,
            type,
            blacklisted_users
        FROM users
        WHERE
            username = :username
    ";


    $query_params = array(
        ':username' => $_POST['username']);


    try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);

    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {

        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }


    $login_ok = false;


    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if($row)
    {
```

followed by password check....

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your `<fieldset>` tag. Add a `</fieldset>` before your closing form tag `</form>`.

EDIT: 
You have some errors in your 
You should add `exit();` after your `header();` 
Also, `$_SESSION['user']` is just a variable, change it to `isset($_SESSION['user'])` because I think that is what you want to do

Also you miss some `{}`

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) { header("location: memberlist.php");  }
         else { // You missed another one here I think?
         if($_SESSION['user']['blacklisted_users'] == 'blocked') {       
         header("location: blocked.php");
         exit();    
     } else { // You missed one here



        header("Location: private.php");
        exit(); // Change die to exit
         }

        else
         {

        $msg = " Username or Password INCORRECT";

          }
```

Comment: I have closed the tags of, if i leave form action blank then it loads but on submit does not refresh to add to count.

Comment: So your page does reload but it doesn't add one to the login_attempts? If so, could you post the code of the function login_attempt_count

Comment: i don't think the function is the problem i think i know what is causing the issue, let me edit question.

Comment: Almost there actually page refreshing now and count adding and user getting blocked after 3 attempts, BUT now $msg not showing on wrong credentials

Comment: I edited my code again, maybe this works (I removed one more possible error)

Comment: iv added the check for username

Comment: Its one or the other either kill page or echo error msg is there no way to do both?